# Linq and sqlclient performance

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to create a web application using ASP.NET. Which method should I use, LINQ or SQL query? Which gives the best performance? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent series by a CLR Performance Architect describing LINQ to SQL performance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2007/06/22/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise I think you'll always be better off with SQL. If you take a look at the generated SQL code which LINQ produces you'll notice that it's not always that top notch.

On the other hand, LINQ isn't slow. It's not as fast as SQL, but it's definitely not slow. If you think about the advantages LINQ provides I would always prefer LINQ over SQL if I have the choice.

If performance is the BIG issue tho, sticking with SQL might be your best shot. If you were just wondering if the difference was that major, and if you don't expect database-performance to be a bottleneck I'd go for LINQ.

Comment: Hear I will use lakes of data. So I thing i use sql. Because I have more knowledge in Sql than Linq . My decesion is Correct or not.? Give your suggestion i do it.

Comment: If you are going to use tons of data going for the regular SQL might be your best pick, because you can control the Queries sent to your server (Especially when you're adept in using/writing SQL). Code-wise I still like to use LINQ tho, because it allows you to write your code faster.. But in your case you can go for SQL if you feel more comfortable with it.